# ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty

Tags: database, wp-config

I'm having trouble trying to setup WordPress for local development, I tried to install it, but even though I fill up the form to setup config file I still get the same error, I can connect to database, but I don't know why it keeps giving that error.

I also tried using the **wp-config-sample.php** but when opening *index.php* it says Error Database Connection.

Comment: What's the value of `$table_prefix`  in your `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: If using a windows pc, make sure the wp directory has permissions. aka give IUSR permissions to write.

Comment: I had this same problem and it turns out that Smart HTTPS (a Firefox and Chrome browser extension) was redirecting POST requests to GET requests which was causing this error as well as the "Please provide a valid username." error message. Since I have this extension in both of my browsers it took me a long time to figure out what the *@#$ was going on but was eventually able to recreate the problem and verify that Smart HTTPS was indeed the issue due to a bug that was triggered when trying to switch to HTTPS when there was not yet valid SSL certificate on my site at the time of installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the table prefix set in the wp-config.php file. It must be matching the same value in tables of your database, the default value is "wp_" but if you used a customized value for your tables to enhance security which is a good practice, you need to update your `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';` where you would change the 'wp_' to the value of your tables.

Comment: It is like that, Idk why it doesn't work properly...

Comment: Are the WP tables created in the database?

Comment: I already solved the problem, but still don't understand it, when using MAMP's MySQL, and PhpStorm's built-in server it didn't worked, but when using MAMP's apache server it did work, not sure if MAMP is encapsulating MySQL instance

Answer (score -1):

this might help someone in the future, but in my case changing PHP version to 7.1.7 (in IIS) fixed it

Comment: You're likely getting down-voted because this answer seems to be off topic and/or lacking in detail. It's unusual to run IIS locally and this question is about local dev environments; it's also not clear how version 7.1.7 of PHP would resolve the issue. It would be helpful if you provided more context to you're answer. For example: where you experiencing the **same** problem? Was changing the PHP version the actually the solution for you? If so, any idea why that may be?

Answer (score -1):

Hi :) Remove mod_security under iis manager -> site -> modules (at least while installing wordpress)